# 301 redirect to wordpress root

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have an old site that I am updating to a wordpress site.  I created 301 redirects, all of which seem to be working perfectly except those that are redirecting to the homepage.  I get an error stating that there are too many redirects.  I've tried multiple iterations and can't seem to get it working.

```
Redirect 301 /about-us.shtml /
Redirect 301 /about-us.shtml /home/
Redirect 301 /about-us.shtml http://example.com/
```

Can someone tell me the proper way to do this?  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That 3rd one looks right, just make sure you put the exact url of your actual website. Access the site, then just copy and paste the domain name without any subdirectories. If you have a trailing slash, it may not work.

Comment: thanks.  removing trailing slash seems to help.

the only exception being when directing from index.shtml to http://example.com presumably because they are both homepage locations?  any tips for sorting that one out?  I don't want to lose any link juice from the old home page.

Comment: Is it a new domain name? Because if you kept the domain name and just moved everything to WordPress, you should keep the same link juice and your homepage shouldn't need to be redirected...unless the old homepage wasn't the root and had /index.shtml at the end

Comment: the old site had index.shtml

how do i pass the link juice over to my wordpress home page?

Comment: You've tried this? 

Redirect 301 /index.shtml https://example.com

That's how I would do it. Since you're keeping the same domain name, your  SEO shouldn't drop too much. You might see a slight drop off at first when Google recrawls the new website, but you should get right back to where you were, if not even better.

Comment: Yes..
Redirect 301 /index.shtml example.com -- this gives a 500 error.
Redirect 301 /index.shtml http://example.com  -- this gives following ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS